# iPad Chrome Shifting Elements to Left

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, safari

I am testing [this](http://hprcc-exp.unl.edu) website on iPad and have discovered that it displays differently on Chrome for iPad than it does on Nexus 7 Chrome. 
Screenshot of Chrome for iPad:
[image: Chrome for iPad]

Screenshot of Chrome for Android:
[image: Chrome for Android]

does anyone know why this happens only on the ipad? I had also confirmed this same behavior for iphone so am assuming this an idevice issue.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add -webkit-justify-content to the css.